# Vaadin: again and again getting entangled in an endless Frontend compilation loop

Tags: vaadin

Since I migrated to Vaadin 22 (I am by now using 23.1.1) I am again and again running into a most annoying situation where the application after a seemingly normal startup suddenly gets caught in an infinite frontend compilation loop - see output below.

The only way around that which I found so far is doing the "Vaadin dance", i.e. to remove all Vaadin and Node generated stuff from my project and then rebuilding again (almost from scratch modulo my source code).
This hits maybe twice per week and I have no idea what could suddenly trigger this. I am typically "happily" editing, compiling, testing and then - boom - after another change and subsequent application restart, suddenly this frontend compilation loop starts happening again.
It's not a total show stopper (at least not so far) but it's simply VERY annoying since this again and again causes an interruption and an extra 30 minutes or so to remove and rebuild everything. :-(

Any idea or suggestion anyone?

```
...
------------------ Starting Frontend compilation. ------------------
2022-07-05 19:29:59,127 INFO  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendTools: The project-specific Node.js version 16.13.0 is older than the required minimum version 16.14.0. Using Node.js from C:\Users\mmo\.vaadin.
2022-07-05 19:29:59,549 INFO  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner: Running Webpack to compile frontend resources. This may take a moment, please stand by...
2022-07-05 19:30:07,878 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
2022-07-05 19:30:07,880 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:50581/
2022-07-05 19:30:07,883 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.43.201:50581/
2022-07-05 19:30:07,885 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'U:\Documents\eclipse\workspace_Vaadin\KIS-Monitoring\target\classes\META-INF\VAADIN\webapp, U:\Documents\eclipse\workspace_Vaadin\KIS-Monitoring\src\main\webapp' directory
2022-07-05 19:30:18,318 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [build-status] : Compiled.

----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------

2022-07-05 19:30:18,328 INFO  [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] com.vaadin.base.devserver.AbstractDevServerRunner: Started Webpack. Time: 21013ms
2022-07-05 19:30:18,452 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: No issues found.
2022-07-05 19:30:22,456 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder:
2022-07-05 19:30:22,457 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: WARNING in InjectManifest has been called multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.
2022-07-05 19:30:22,460 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [build-status] 1 warning were reported.
2022-07-05 19:30:22,461 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [build-status] : Compiled.

----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------

2022-07-05 19:30:22,471 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: No issues found.
2022-07-05 19:30:22,902 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder:
2022-07-05 19:30:22,903 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: WARNING in InjectManifest has been called multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.
2022-07-05 19:30:22,910 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [build-status] 1 warning were reported.
2022-07-05 19:30:22,911 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: [build-status] : Compiled.

----------------- Frontend compiled successfully. -----------------

2022-07-05 19:30:22,921 INFO  [dev-server-output] com.vaadin.base.devserver.DevServerOutputTracker$Finder: No issues found.
...
<etc. ad infinitum...>
```

Versions:
Java: 17
Vaadin: 23.1.7 (which has the same "spurious effect")
npm: 8.15.0

Those loops happen regardless of whether I start this on the command-line or from within my IDE (Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0))

Comment: Is this loop happening, while you have the IDE open or some build-tool running? Does it also happen, if you close all things with the potential to manipulate your project?  This might include processes in the background (e.g. gradle might spin off some daemon for faster startup).

Comment: Might be helpful if you list all the environmental information that might be relevant, including version numbers - OS, IDE if you're running inside one, build tool (Maven / Gradle), node / npm, Java